# Tomcat downloads folder is empty whenever I install a new war file

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, war

I know just enough about Tomcat to be dangerous to myself and others.

To deploy, I create a WAR file (export from Eclipse), then copy that WAR file to the \apache-tomcat-7.0.23\webapps\ folder, then restart using \apache-tomcat-7.0.23\bin\startup.bat.

My webapp writes PDF files to a downloads folder, which as I understand must be in the WebContent folder in my Eclipse project.

Problem is, when I install a new WAR file, when Tomcat unzips it, it wipes out the contents of the download folder, so users' prior outputs are lost.

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it's not right (at least, not very convenient) to save user files to WebContent folder of the web application. WebContent folder is meant for resources that are distributed inside the web application archive.

It's common practice to use some specific location on disk for **user files that are planned to be reused**.

1) To specify the location in configuration file, create file app.properties in the root of application CLASSPATH. In this file you will have the property

```
user.pdfs.location=/path/to/user/pdfs
```

To read the property use the following code in your servlet:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream propsStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("app.properties");

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(propsStream);

String userPdfsPath = properties.getProperty("user.pdfs.location");
```

So you'll always be able to change location of PDFs in "/WEB-INF/classes/app.properties" file in already created WAR.

2) Or you may pass parameter to the Tomcat's JVM:

```
-Duser.pdfs.location="/path/to/user/pdfs"
```

To read value of the parameter use the following code:

```
String userPdfsPath = System.getProperty("user.pdfs.location");
```

**Another popular (but not always right) approach** is to save files to database as BLOBs. Consider that in that case you sometimes may have problems with application perfomance or backups.

**If you want to work with temporary files** (for example, you want to create PDFs for users just to download) you should use JVM's temp directory for that. To get temp directory use

```
String tempDirPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
```

Or simply create temp PDF file with

```
File tempPDF = File.createTempFile("temp-", ".pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  I am fully prepared to store these files elsewhere!  Can you be more specific about how I would specify "the location in a configuration file of the application".  All programs have been setup to write reports to a directory, the name of which I have stored in a MySQL table, and is made available to all servlets.  But I think there has be some parameter within Tomcat that says "when the user types in this url (or beginning of url), then look for that in this folder".  Where would that parameter be, and what is it called?  Thanks again.

Comment: @BillQualls I don't know about such a parameter in Tomcat. But you can always write special servlet to return file to user. Specify "url-pattern" of the servlet as `download-servlet` and pass "file" parameter to it: `/download-servlet?file=user.pdf`. Here's an example of similar servlet: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/SendPDFfile.htm

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you redeploy any application,both the war file and the extracted folder is wiped out by Tomcat .So obviously if you are storing anything inside extracted war path, it's going to get deleted at the time of next redeploy.
Also, it is not usually not a good practice to store any user data in extracted web application. It would be better and convenient to you also if you choose any other path to create user files.